# CKeitor edited text gone on submission validation failed

Tags: php, forms, ckeditor

I used CKeditor customized plug-in in a form. Once the form submitted, if the validation on the server-side are not passed, the browser doesn't proceed to the next page. However, the previously edited texts are also gone. I tried to get the posted data. However, this is not working. Thanks ahead for anyone helps!

```
<form method = "post" action = "">
<textarea name="comments"  value="<?php echo $_POST ["comments"]; ?>" ></textarea>
</form>
```

CKeidtor is set up like this:

```
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'comments' );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form has a submit type button with name "save" then do like this or simply replace whatever name you have given to your submit type button

```
<textarea name="comments"><?php if(isset($_POST['save'])) { echo $_POST ["comments"]; } ?></textarea>
```

Textarea doesn't have value property. Whatever you wish to retain must come between the opening and closing tags.